# load userDefinedForm in costum template Silverstripe

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe

Hi all I have little problem on Silverstripe 3.1 I am trying to pull out Form from UserDefinedForm module but no success maybe some one had that problem?

My controller function:

```
public function getContactPageForm(){
    $record = DataObject::get_one("UserDefinedForm", "URLSegment = 'contactpageform'");
    $results = new UserDefinedForm_Controller($record);
    return $results;
}
```

My template:

```
<% if getContactPageForm %>
   <% loop getContactPageForm %>
      $Form
   <% end_loop %>
<% end_of %>
```

PLZ HELP

Answer (score 0):

Finded solution myself just extended UserDefinedForm not Page